# Is not(A XOR B) the same as (!A XOR !B)?

Tags: xor, algebra

I would like to know if !(A xor B) is equal to (!A xor !B)?
I am struggling to understand the logic behind this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not equal. You could check the following table for further explanation.

```
+---+---+-------+--------+----+----+-------+
| A | B | (A^B) | !(A^B) | !A | !B | !A^!B |
+---+---+-------+--------+----+----+-------+
| 0 | 0 |     0 |      1 |  1 |  1 |     0 |
| 0 | 1 |     1 |      0 |  1 |  0 |     1 |
| 1 | 0 |     1 |      0 |  0 |  1 |     1 |
| 1 | 1 |     0 |      1 |  0 |  0 |     0 |
+---+---+-------+--------+----+----+-------+
```

Edit: Computing `!(A^B)` without using NOT operation with A, B, A' and B'

`XOR(A, B) = OR(AND(A, B'), AND(A', B))`

After using DeMorgan for the equation above:

`NOT XOR(A,B) = AND(OR(A', B), OR(A, B'))`

Comment: Thanks @4turkuaz, is there a nicer way to get !(A XOR B) without using an NOT afterwards given A,B and their complements?

Comment: Yes, there is. With the prior information `XOR(A, B) = OR(AND(A, B'), AND(A', B))` we might extract the equation you needed.  After using DeMorgan the equation you're looking for is: `(A' OR B) AND (A OR B')`

Comment: May I use (A' XOR B)? I made a truth table for it and it seems correct. (Or (A XOR B') for that matter)

Comment: Well, it seems like you might, but not sure if this is the purpose targeted. I've updated my answer with the theoretical form.

Answer (score 1):

No they're not.

`A xor B` is equal to `1` if and only if either `A` or either `B` is `1` but not both.  Therefore `!(A xor B)` is equal to `1` if and only if both `A` and `B` are equal.

Whereas with `(!A xor !B)` you first flip the bits and then do the XOR.  So `(!A xor !B) = (A xor B)`.

Here is the truth table for the first one:

```
A | B | A xor B | !(A xor B)
============================
0 | 0 |       0 |          1
0 | 1 |       1 |          0
1 | 0 |       1 |          0
1 | 1 |       0 |          1
```

and for the second one:

```
A | B | !A | !B | (!A xor !B)
=============================
0 | 0 |  1 |  1 |         0
0 | 1 |  1 |  0 |         1
1 | 0 |  0 |  1 |         1
1 | 1 |  0 |  0 |         0
```

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, use truth tables. A and B can be 1 or 0 so:

```
A xor B:
0 1
1 0

! (A xor B)
1 0
0 1

! A xor ! B:
0 1
1 0
```

So, the answer is no. They seem to be the same as the initial xor.

Answer (score 1):

Going step by step, and looking at the resulting column, we see that they do not result in the same output based on the same input.

| A | B | A XOR B | not(A XOR B) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

| A | B | !A | !B | (!A XOR !B) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |